# How to use RabbitMQ message as a "Rest Api" to find entities?

Tags: rest, rabbitmq, message-queue

I'm having a problem to solve in an application. I'll show an example about it.

I have a rabbitmq queue on a system that is responsable to return Orders, called by another systems (the communication among these systems is only throught message). Until then, **the only possible Order search was by the order code**.

It works well. When I search by order code, I also filter by the order with contracts and deleted (logically). So, if the order has no contracts or it was deleted, the query doesn't return registers.

**Now, one of that systems needs to find Orders without contracts and/or deleted.**

Basically, I believe I need to build the same logic used in an API rest like this one, but using a queue message:

```
/api/orders?id=123455?deleted=true&hasContracts=true
```

Do that it's easy with message. I just need send a message with this format.

```
{
    "code": 123,
    "deleted": true,
    "hasContract": true
}
```

Mapping the values for `Long` and `Boolean` classes. If the information was `null`,  this filter will be ignored by the query, except the `code` that's mandatory.

The doubt is: is this makes sense? I didn't find anything about this subject on the Internet. Create a queue for each case is not an option, because it will be hard for us to implement many queues.

Comment: Could you please specify how the acquiring system will figure out that some particular order in queue is what it was asking for? I mean, there are plenty of orders in the queue, don't you want only some particular be handled?

Comment: I'm not sure to get exactly your use case. When you say "I have a RabbitMQ queue that is responsible to return Orders", do you mean you have one queue and many consumers on it? Today, how do other systems query your API? And how do they get back the answer?

Comment: We have a more than one micro service that ask for Orders and one microservice responsable for return the asked Order (we call him as `order-service`). The communication is synchronous (RPC - Remote Procedure Call) using RabbitMQ: the service send a order code in a message for a queue and the `order-service` get the message from the queue and return de Order for the service that requested it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It makes sense to me; using RPC with RabbitMQ is like RPC with HTTP/gRPC/..., so you have many options here:

- if you need a great flexibility, you can

  - create your own query language (like in the example above)
  - use something like GraphQL
- if your use cases are limited, you can choose to segregate the API endpoints with several routing keys (REST-over-AMQP).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, can I somehow get messages with HTTP API by filtering it ? For example, I want to get messages by some properties or headers ?

Comment: Not sure to understand your question: what HTTP API? The RabbitMQ admin API? It is not a good way to use RabbitMQ if you mean it.